# Django nginx + uwsgi [error] : *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, uwsgi

I am getting 502 error and in error log [error] 18959#18959: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream.......

```
upstream django {
    server          127.0.0.1:7000; 
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     ec2-instance-address.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
    access_log      /srv/project/logs/access-nginx.log;
    error_log       /srv/project/logs/error-nginx.log;
location / {
    uwsgi_pass      django;
    include         /srv/project/conf/envs/stage/uwsgi/params;
}

location /static/ {
    root            /srv/project/;
    index           index.html index.htm;
}

location /media/ {
    root            /srv/project/;
    index           index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ ^/favicon.(\w*)$ {
    alias /srv/book-stage/static/favicon.$1;
}
}
```

uwsgi.ini file for the project.

## mysite_uwsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]

socket          = :7000
chmod-socket    = 666
uid             = nginx
gid             = nginx
master          = true
enable-threads  = true
processes       = 2

virtualenv      = /srv/project
chdir           = /srv/project
pythonpath      = /srv/project
module          = conf.wsgi
pidfile         = /srv/project/uwsgi/stage.pid
daemonize       = /srv/project/logs/uwsgi.log
touch-reload    = /srv/project/uwsgi/touch.py
vacuum          = true

log-format      = %(addr) - %(user) [%(ltime)] "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" %(status) %(size) "%(referer)" "%(uagent)"
```

after `uwsgi --ini /srv/project/conf/envs/stage/uwsgi/stage.ini` 
nginx error.log updated to new error

```
[error]: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: Your uwsgi.ini file also needs research, can you post it too?

Comment: @abcdn updated in question.

Comment: Looks like should be working. What do you see when you run `uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini`?

Comment: @abcdn [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /srv/project/conf/envs/stage/uwsgi/stage.ini

Comment: In nginx error log error changed to '[error] 21705#21705: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream'

Comment: Try changing `socket          = :7000` to `http-socket = :7000` and visit 127.0.0.1:7000 in your browser to see, if the app works at all or not. Nginx will not work with `http-socket`, but this may be helpful as a debug step. Also examine `/srv/project/logs/uwsgi.log` and post the errors here.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting nginx and intiating uwsgi by `uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini` after adding `unix:///tmp/project.sock` to stream section of nginx configuration and `socket = /tmp/project.sock` to uwsgi.ini file solved the problem for me.